# Chef Knife command - PowerShell "query session" failing with return code 1, although command is executed successfully

Tags: powershell, chef, winrm, knife

I am facing a peculiar problem in executing chef knife commands for PowerShell remotely.

Command is executed successfully, however the return code is 1 with an error.

```
> %CPath% && knife winrm '%IP_Val%' --winrm-shell Powershell 'query session' -x %username% -p %password%  -m

%IPAddress%  SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
%IPAddress% >services                                    0  Disc
%IPAddress%  console                                     1  Conn
%IPAddress%                    %Username%          3  Disc
%IPAddress%  rdp-tcp                                 65536  Listen
ERROR: Failed to execute command on %IPAddress% return code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like its something to do with WinRM. I replaced "query session" with "qwinsta" which solved the problem.

Need to check RCA on Winrm